# DataTemplate with button in wp7 silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I writing wp7 silverlight app.
I have a listbox with items. I want each item to have different DataTemplate. I'm using OnContentChanged event and read the template to the ContentTemplate.
My problem is with buttons on the template. On runtime the buttons event handler is not found, and I get exception. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this (to have different DataTemplate for each item) is to implement some kind of DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: It worked! In my first attempt I used the same DataTemplateSelector, but my templates was in a separate xaml file, so there was no code behind. I used this example for the template and it worked great!